Download full web page and save without a deep directory structure? Also, bypass paywall?
So, I want to be able to download a web page in a way similar to what https://archive.is does.
Using wget -p -E -k usually produces a decent result - but this result is somewhat hard to handle. For example, after wget -p -E -k https://news.sky.com/story/yazidi-woman-kidnapped-by-islamic-state-freed-from-gaza-after-decade-in-captivity-13227540 I got a directory names news.sky.com and the page was available as news.sky.com/story/yazidi-woman-kidnapped-by-islamic-state-freed-from-gaza-after-decade-in-captivity-13227540.html while other necessary files for the page were scattered around in this same news.sky.com directory.
I'd prefer to have something similar to how browsers can "save a page" - the page file in the current directory plus a "something_files" subdirectory where the necessities are. I understand I can kinda do that by moving the site directory structure into that files subdirectory and creating a redirect page next to it, but I'd prefer to do it properly if possible.
There are also cases pf paywalls that archive.is successfully bypasses but wget -p -E -k does not. For example, with https://www.nytimes.com/2014/10/28/magazine/theo-padnos-american-journalist-on-being-kidnapped-tortured-and-released-in-syria.html , archive.is produced a perfect paywall-less copy, while wget -p -E -k produced the start of the article hanging on "verifying access". I'd like to be doing what archive.is does.
Advice on how to change these things would be much appreciated.

Do you know that archive.is has any special trick? Isn't it just users submitting URLs for archiving, so presumably using their own login credentials?

What you are trying to achieve is to create a MHTML document. I am not aware of a command tool for doing that (but it should be relatively easy to create one) OTOH there are browser plugins for Chrome and Firefox which would be used with webautomation.

I can offer the script that I use to clone sites for offline use.  It does a decent job for general site copying.
#!/bin/bash

input="$1"

ua='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0'

#--force-directories
#domains="$(cat omit.txt)" --exclude-domains="$domains"
#excludes="" --reject-regex="$excludes"

wget --referer --robots=no --recursive --output-file="$input-wget.log" \
     --page-requisites --ignore-length --adjust-extension --wait=".1" --user-agent "$ua" \
     --content-on-error --no-cache --trust-server-names --no-check-certificate \
     --convert-links --keep-session-cookies  "$input"

exit 0

Save as: website_save.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x website_save.sh
Usage: ./website_save.sh www.example.com

Something I should point out, to help people unfamiliar with web development, is the way client/server configurations work.
If the site you are copying is more than a simple web page, and requires the use of AJAX, PHP, use of a database, websockets... or whatever it may be, it's not going to work locally by just opening index.html.  It needs the page running over an actual http server, which provides the services to properly interact with the browser when it makes server-side requests.
A quick way to achieve functionality for most offline sites, you will need to use five-server or a similar http://localhost... configuration.
This answer explains, in detail, how to isolate an offline site to appear as a local application.  The JSON editor in this answer is a good example of a page that needs to run as localhost to function offline.  Everything it explains about five-server, or using php -S, is exactly how you accomplish this.
